# Not an interval graph, so what is it?

Tags: graph-theory

I've constructed a graph in a simular way an interval graph would be constructed from the overlap of intervals. But my intervals are from a modular domain.

[image: Modular overlap]

Given $\mathit{interval} \equiv \mathit{chordal} \cap \mathit{cocomparability}$ it is obvious the above graph is not an interval graph since it is not chordal. See cycle 2-4-5-6-1-7-2.

My question: is this just a cocomparability graph or does it fall under another classification?

Comment: The complement of the graph has a transitive ordering (1,4) (1,3) (1,2) (3,2) (6,2) (6,7) (5,2) (5,7)

Comment: A quick Google search led me to *[circular-arc graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular-arc_graph)*. Is that what you want?

Comment: Thanks @RahulNarain, do you know any equivilance relations between circular-arc graphs and other classes of graphs?

Comment: No idea. As I said, I just found this through a quick Google search for "interval graph on a circle" or something like that. The Wikipedia article has a lot of references which might help.

Answer (score 2):

The circular arc graphs are a superset of the interval graphs, where rather than being intervals on a line, the vertices are represented as arcs around a circle. As you noticed, the chordless cycles are not forbidden subgraphs for the circular-arc graphs.